# Ubuntu 20.04 can't enter login screen

Tags: boot, 20.04

**Before presenting the problem, I should say that I know that it has been asked several times. I tried many ways to fix it, but none works. So, I ask it again with my unique scenario.**

I use Ubuntu 20.04 dual boot with Windows 10. The former is located on an HDD (`sda2` here) and the latter is on an SSD. I have used Ubuntu for several years and works fine. **One day I woke up and found that my files can't be modified (error occurs) and all stuff seems to be read-only.** Then, I turned off my computer and there come up many error messages about `sda2`, before totally shutting down.

Then, I power it on again, but it can't boot. Only the `initramfs` prompt show ups and hints me to type `fsck` to fix disk errors. I follow the hint to resolve the problem.

After that, `initramfs` won't show up, but there are still a lot of errors such as:

```
systemd-journald.. Fail to rewrite entry(......); ignoring: Read-only file system
```

Then, I did something I can't remember, those errors stoped and I can see that Ubuntu is loading (the circle is spinning). At this time, the login screen should show up, but it didn't. The only thing is a blinking cursor at the top-left corner (sometimes a real cursor will show up). At this point I can login by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> and access my files.

So far I'm stuck here and following is some analysis about what I did:

1. Hardware problem? I don't think so, since the other partition on the HDD, owned by Windows 10, works fine. Also, the storage on Ubuntu seems fine (checked by using pseudo terminal).
2. NVIDIA bug? I don't think so. I have used Ubuntu several years on this PC and it worked fine.
3. GDM 3 bug? I have tried using `lightdm`, `sddm` and re-install `gdm3`. All of them go to same result: blinking cursor.
4. I harmed the system? Probably. Before not being able to boot, I was  developing the Linux kernel. But recently, I only recompiled it again and again (didn't install it).

To me, the current situation (stuck before login) seems really like a problem with the desktop manager. But the weird thing is that I can't understand why it can't work suddenly.

Do you guys have similar issue? Or any suspicion about what might be the problem?

Comment: I wouldn't try and boot your system (and if I did I wouldn't try and make any changes) until you've verified the health of your *file-system*. A *file-system* flips from RW (read-write) to RO (read-only) because a command told it to, or the system detected errors & thus by flipping the *fs* RO any data corruption or data loss is avoided.  I'd boot a *live* media (such as installation media) & check your *file-system* (`fsck` or GUI tool) and if errors are detected & fixed you'll have a normal boot next time you try. I'd also check the health of your drives (that's just me though; habit).

Comment: @guiverc, thanks your reply. I've already tried to use live bootable USB (linux-mint) to check it. Unfortunately, I can't fix `sda2` by `fsck` on linux-mint. It said sda2 is busy and can't be umount.

Comment: Given I don't know what *file-system* is on `sda2` (we only know what you tell us) I can't provide any help there...  I doubt anything is different with Linux Mint, but as it's a different OS (that uses runtime *adjustments*) I cannot be sure (no on-topic OS uses runtime *adjustments*)

Comment: fs on sda2 is ext4. I think `fsck` has fixed the errors ( at least there's not message about sda error and hint to call `fsck`)

Comment: If your Mint system was like a Ubuntu one, and you're using a *live* system as I suggest, no `ext4` system is mounted except on user demand; so why did you `mount` it?   Swap is the only system that *may* get auto-mounted by a Ubuntu system used in *live* mode; but we don't support Mint here as it's a different system.

Comment: Actually I have used Mint to extend Ubuntu's disk partition several days ago. It works fine and it implies `sda2` is unmount when I using Mint. I think something go wrong, now, when I using Mint, `sda2` is still mounted. Then, I can't call `fsck` in Mint properly.

Comment: @guiverc, I finally saw `sda2` is unmounted from Mint. By using `fsck`, it seems health (no error, `/dev/sda2: clean, .....` ). But when I get back to Ubuntu, I still see my `sda2` with **errors=remount-ro** tag. (can't fix by `mount -o remount,rw /dev/sda2`)

Comment: `errors=remount-ro` is not an issue (it's there on my / mount in my *file-system table* fstab; I'd expect it to be, as it lets me explore issues if I have any & protect data should an error be detected; my *fs* is RW).  I don't know what you mean by 'tag', but answers to issues are usually found in logs, or provided after commands. We can't read your logs being limited to whatever you provide; but I'd read logs, check your `fstab` & ensure it matches your actual file-systems, read the errors/messages after commands (or after issues occur in logs; `dmesg` `journalctl` etc).

Comment: Should I check them in ubuntu recover mode?

Comment: @guiverc, thanks your suggestion. I dump the `dmesg` and found many "IO error dev/sda sector...". There're lot of discussion about it and indicate that it was caused by hardware-issue. But, I using SMART-tool to check the hardware by `smartctl -H /dev/sda2` and my disk pass the test. So, my problem might be software issue?

Comment: From the little you've provided me (ie. details posted here), I'd expect hardware issues and not software issues. Good components can fail when giving bad power... and if your PSU is marginal, tests will pass when the machine is quiet, but if it gets warm, fans go on (drawing more power, GPU draws more power etc) power to a drive may drop below threshold & IO errors occur; this is a hardware issue where the PSU is to blame (it cannot provide enough power for the components connected to it; or the builder used small a PSU for the box; or it's now too old and can't produce rated power anymore)

Comment: Your likely response will be to doubt this as "windows 10 is still good".... yeah it is for now... Windows 10 if it came with the machine would have been configured to not draw too much power & thus survive longer... but if the PSU is marginal, you'll likely notice issues there is weeks-months too... problems tend to show on newer GNU/Linux installs first (along with BSD etc) as they come with less power-reducing tweaks active (until added by users; windows has them added by the seller of he unit who wants to market good battery life, high-energy-star rating etc. in sales literature..)

Comment: ＠guiverc, Thanks for detailed analysis, I re-install ubuntu in same disk partition. Now, it works good. I would assume that my power/disk is fine and the thing happened to me is software issue. (Before this question, I've used tool: gpart in order to extend my ubuntu partition. I think this is the reason cause those weird behavior)

Comment: refer prior comments. You've seen your hardware given warnings of potential problems that are coming, and usually just get worse until full failure occurs. Me I'd suggest checking your hardware & of course keep plenty of backups. if the hardware is faulty and you're ignoring warning signs... keep plenty more backups as you risk finding some are corrupted due to ignored *warning* signs of hardware issues. If it was software, you'd get the same failure every time. if you check and it installed to same innodes as before (ie. same area of disk), PSU looks more likely.  behavior your warnings